# Is "You're an early bird, don't you?" correct grammar?

Tags: grammaticality, question-tags

I had a discussion with a friend.

He said to someone:

> "You're an early bird, don't you?"

I said it should be:

> "You're an early bird, aren't you?"

It is a regular tag question; if you start with 'are', you end with 'aren't you'.

I don't have enough knowledge of linguistics to properly debate with him on this.
Is his way of asking this in any way valid?

Comment: You are right. The standard tag uses the same verb, so _you are_ and _do you_ don't match.

Comment: Also, the *bird* in that sentence is a noun (look: it's being modified by an adjective), so one *ISes* it, not *DOes* it. It'd have to be a verb to be *done*.

Comment: A slightly different way to say what Dan Bron wrote: "You are an early bird" refers to a pattern of behavior with the adjectival phrase 'early bird'. "Do you not?" implies an accompanying verb, e.g., "Do you not _dance_ when it rains?" or, "Do you not _enjoy_ the sunshine?"

Comment: This sort of question is not suitable for this list and should be on SE English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0):

You are totally right. "You're an early bird, don't you?" is incorrect.

One way to explain this to him might be by first clarifying what the first sentence is saying. This should be easy to explain.

> "You're an early bird."

The verb is 'to be' and it is saying that the 'you' person **is** an 'early bird'.

Now, you could explain to him what a tag question is but I do not think that would necessarily be helpful in this case.
I would instead recommend that you then explain that the second part of the sentence is only to confirm your first statement. With your first statement asking if 'you' **is** *(to be)* an 'early bird', the second could only ask the same, '**aren't** *(to be)* you?'

Another way of looking at it is to ask:

> "Are you an early bird?" vs. "Do you an early bird?"

It is pretty clear from that.

Now I know you did not ask for how to explain it but I hope this helps!